# Get current logged user in Windows Server via browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap, kerberos

So... It's my first question here, so take it easy, and tell me if I can improve anything on the question itself.

The problem is, we are trying to make a intranet in `node.js` and one of the prerequisites is that the user don't need to authenticate everytime he logs in the machine.

We already have a application in `php` that uses kerberos and ldap for auth, but we are trying to avoid `php` for further development.

So, the main question is: There is a way to get the current logged user in Windows Server, via `node.js`? Or some other way develop an SSO network with `node.js` ?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and tests, found that `express-ntlm` was the best option for node, and gets the user login of the machine, even if the node application is running via Windows Server.

```
ntlm = require('express-ntlm');

var app = express();

app.use(ntlm({
    debug: function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        console.log.apply(null, args);
    },
    domain: '<domain>',
    domaincontroller: '<ldap://ldap.com>',
}));

app.all('*', function(request, response) {
    response.end(JSON.stringify(request.ntlm)); // {"DomainName":"MYDOMAIN","UserName":"MYUSER","Workstation":"MYWORKSTATION"}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.ntlm));
});

app.listen(3003);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a safe way for authentication without logging in. I would recommend to use [node-ldapjs](https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs), this way you don't need PHP to communicate with ldap.